# I'm struggling to call this unusually structured Javascript function from XUL

Tags: javascript, parameters, xul

`(function(aLeftPane) { ... }) ("History")`.

The complete function is here: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/t2QPtRET)

I haven't been able to get my head round how the contents of the seconds set of brackets gets passed into the functions in the first set.

I want to make the hard-coded "History" into a variable. I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a more regular function, but I haven't been able to pass parameters to it successfully.

The XUL that calls the function currently looks like this: `oncommand="madeUpWrapperName('history');"`

Comment: A `()` after a function invokes the function. Doesn't matter if it's `foo("bar")` or `(function foo(x) {})("bar")` or `(function(x) {})("bar")`

Comment: Thank you, I have re-structured the function as function foo("history") {} which makes sense to me, where "history" substituted for a new variable. But the variable gets ignored.

Comment: Could you reduce your pastebin code to something that *only* demonstrates the problem? (not the rest of your code). It's not clear what you mean by "the variable gets ignored".

Comment: The parameter works as a hard-coded string, but not when passed to the function as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function(aLeftPane) { ... }) ("History")
```

Is *not* an unusually structured function, it's a common pattern to *encapsulate* code in JS. What it does is declare an anonymous function and then immediately call it. It is used very often by libraries to create the lib entry point and cleanly separate private from public code without polluting the global namespace.

In your case, you actually want to unwrap the function :

```
function unwrapped(aLeftPane) 
{
    /**
     * Select left panel in Library.
     *
     * @param aBrowser Browser object in selected tab.
    ...

}
```

then, in your xul or somewhere else:

```
oncommand="unwrapped('History');"
```

Comment: Thank you! It's hard to get help when you're brand new. I'd been on this for hours trying every combination